# Memory leak caused by event listeners attached to knockout removed dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, typescript, knockout-2.0

I am using knockout and it's foreach binding to bind table rows into a table.  I don't update the UI to add or remove rows, it's all done by knockout. I am also using the tipped js library to add tooltips to those rows.  The problem is that I have no reference to the row in typescript or typescript d.ts definitions for tipped js.   I got it working with this ugly piece of code.

```
setInterval(function () {
    Tipped.create('.tipped'); // create tooltips and listeners
    $(".tipped").removeClass("tipped"); // don't attach twice
}, 500);
```

This would add the events only once, and then skip them in the future.

The issue is that although knockout removes it's own binding when a row is removed, tipped does not.   This is causing a memory leak as more and more event listeners are left for elements that no longer exist on the page.  They are never garbage collected.

Is the solution going to be a custom foreach binding that adds and removes my tipped?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's pretty, but it works to fix my leak

```
setInterval(function () {
    Tipped.create('.tipped');
    $(".tipped").bind('destroyed', function () {
        Tipped.remove($(this));
    });
    $(".tipped").removeClass("tipped");
}, 500);

(function ($) {
    $.event.special.destroyed = {
        remove: function (o) {
            if (o.handler) {
                o.handler.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery)
```